# Dynamic Fields Not Working in Cloudsearch

Tags: amazon-web-services, search, dynamic, indexing

When using Cloudsearch I am faced with this error when trying to upload a document.

[image]

My document looks like this

```
[
{
"type": "add",
"id": "1",
"fields": {
  "timezone": "Europe/London",
  "id": "2653822",
  "location": "51.479999999999997, -3.1800000000000002",
  "country": "GB",
  "placetype": "settlement",
  "fcode": "PPLA",
  "population": "302139",
  "name_en": "Cardiff",
  "name_cy": "Caerdydd",
  "name_ga": "Caerdydd",
  "name_gd": "Caerdydd",
  "containerid": "3333241",
  "container_en": "Cardiff",
  "container_cy": "Dinas a Sir Caerdydd",
  "container_ga": "Cardiff",
  "container_gd": "Cardiff"
}}]
```

And my index looks like this
[image]

Does anybody know why this isn't working? I would have thought the pattern in my documents (name_en, name_cy etc) would match the index pattern of `name_*`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok for anybody else with this problem, this is a case of poor UX.
It seems that when analysing documents, the parser does not pick up dynamic fields. If your document is actually invalid, you will not be able to upload and an error will be shown.

This can be tested by adding a random field such as

```
"invalid-field" : "somethingInvalid"
```

I then tested my search endpoint by hitting

```
my-search-endpoint/2013-01-01/search?q=name_cy:%27Caerdydd%27&q.parser=structured
```

and got the desired result.

Comment: Sorry I'm still having this issue - could you elaborate on the issue and solution a little more?